# How to set outerHTML with using of cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, cheerio

could someone answer me, how to properly set outerHTML of element by using cheerio.
I have a problem with that.

Example: Let's say I have an HTML structure below

```
<div class="page-info">
   <span>Here is an example #1</span>
</div>
<div class="page-info">
   <span>Here is an example #2</span>
</div>
```

Parsing it via cheerio and adding some manipulations

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(`above HTML is here`);

let elemList = $('.page-info');
for (const elem of elemList) {
   let innerHtml = $(elem).html(); //<span>Here is an example #1</span>
   let outerHtml = $.html(elem); //<div class="page-info"><span>Here is an example #1</span></div>
   let replacedHtml = '<p>totally new html structure</p>';

   $(elem).html(replacedHtml);
}
```

As a result I expect to have all divs to be replaced with p. But only spans are replaced with p.
I want to get result:

```
<p>totally new html structure</p>
<p>totally new html structure</p>
```

but it's next

```
<div class="page-info">
   <p>totally new html structure</p>
</div>
<div class="page-info">
   <p>totally new html structure</p>
</div>
```

Am I missing something in documentation to the cheerio?
Please point me where I'm doing it wrongly.

Regards, Oleh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replaceWith` (Replaces matched elements with content) to replace the node:

```
$(".page-info").replaceWith("<p>totally new html structure</p>");
```

Using `each`:

```
let elemList = $(".page-info");
elemList.each((i, elem)=> {
   $(elem).replaceWith("<p>totally new html structure</p>")
})
```